# Google Analytics Polymer Elements Demo not working

Tags: javascript, github, google-analytics, polymer, demo

I'm really new at Google Analytics and I'm facing a problem with Google Analytics Polymer Elements, see [demo](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-analytics?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=google-analytics-query)

If I sign in it works, but after I downloaded the source code from GitHub I'm not able to make it work!
In the GitHub demo there are some "imports" with relative path and I downloaded all of it and I set my local path, but the only thing I can see is this:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the chrome javascript console provide any useful errors? Have you set up your project credentials?